# Validating POST values

Tags: php, html

I made a page with php to find out the grade by typing marks(LOL)
they are namely index.php and php.php
When i type the marks in index page , everything works great

But when i directly jump into the php.php , the fail message is coming , IDK why.

And i want to fix it .

index.php

```
     <html> 
     <head>
     <title>Know your grade</title>
     <style type="text/css">
     input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
     input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
     margin: 0;
     }

     input[type=number] {
     -moz-appearance:textfield;
      }
      body{
      height: auto;
      max-width: 100%;
      }
      #abt{
      opacity: 0.3;
      -webkit-transition: opacity 2s;
      transition-timing-function: ease;
      text-shadow: 0.5px 0.5px blue;
      }
      #abt:hover{
      opacity: 1;
      }
      #wn{
      text-decoration: none;
      color: black;
      text-shadow: 0.5px 0.5px navy blue;
     -webkit-transition: color 0.5s;
      }
      #wn:hover{
      color:red;
      }
      #reset{
      -webkit-transition: color 1s , background-color 1.5s;
      }
      #reset:hover{
      color:blue;
      background-color: yellow;
      }
      </style>
      </head>
      <body>
      <h1 style="text-align:center;font-family:MS comic Sans">Whats your      grade?</h1>
       <div style="text-align:center;font-family:Georgia;">
        <form type="text" method="post" action="php.php">
    Enter Marks : <input id="marks" name="marks" min="0" step="0.5" type="number" placeholder="                 marks                 " required="required" oninput="validity.valid||(value='')">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"><br><br>
    <input type="reset" name="Reset" id="reset">
    </form>
    </div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <p style="text-align:center">How to use this : Enter marks of a subject       , Press Enter or Click submit and know your grade.</p>
     <p style="text-align:center"><b>Note:</b> Maximum marks is 100 </p>
     <div id="abt" style="bottom:0px;position:fixed;right:0px;margin-right:10px;margin-bottom:5px">
     <span style="margin:0 auto;display:table;"><u>About</u></span><br>
     Developer : <u>Srijan Mukhrjee</u><br>
     Proposed on : <u>26-09-2016</u><br>
     Completed on : <u>26-09-2016</u><br>
     Version : <u>2.<span style="font-size: 10px">1</span></u> (Latest   version)<br>
     <span style="display: table;margin: 0 auto"><a href="Whatsnew.html" id="wn">(What's New)</a></span>
      </div>
      </body>
      </html>
```

Php.php

```
    <?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
    $Mymarks = $_POST['marks'];
    $fail = "<h3>We are sorry to say that you failed with poor marks - work    hard</h3>"."<h4>Improve yourself and try better next time</h4>"."<h4>Your marks    is "."<span style='color:red'>".$Mymarks."</span>"." </h5>";
    if($Mymarks >=92 && $Mymarks <=100){
    echo "You have got A1 "."Your marks is ".$Mymarks;
    }
    elseif($Mymarks >=84 && $Mymarks <=91){
    echo "You have got A2 "."<br>"."And your marks is ".$Mymarks ;
    }
    elseif($Mymarks >=76 && $Mymarks <=83){
    echo "You have got B1 "."<br>"."And your marks is ".$Mymarks;
    }
    elseif($Mymarks >=68 && $Mymarks <=75){
    echo "You have got B2 "."<br>"."And your marks is ".$Mymarks;
    }
    elseif($Mymarks >=60 && $Mymarks <=67){
    echo "You have got C1 "."<br>Try better next time<br>"."And your marks is ".$Mymarks;
    }
    elseif($Mymarks >=52 && $Mymarks <=59){
    echo "You have got C2 "."<br>Improve yourself<br>"."And your marks is  ".$Mymarks;
     }
    elseif($Mymarks >=44 && $Mymarks <=58){
    echo "You have got D1 "."<br>Improve yourself<br>"."And your marks is ".$Mymarks;
     }
     elseif($Mymarks >=36 && $Mymarks <=57){
     echo "You have got E1 "."<br>Improve yourself<br>"."And your marks is ".$Mymarks;
     }
     elseif($Mymarks < 36){
     echo $fail;
     } 
     elseif($Mymarks > 100){
     echo "You Entered Marks greater than 100";
     }
     ?>
```

When i directly open the php without going through the index.php the fail message is observed

How can i fix it?

Comment: Because when comparing `null` to an integer, `null` gets type cast to `integer` to do the comparison, and the int cast of null, is 0. You should be making sure `$_POST['marks']` exists using `isset` and checking that it is an numeric value, potentially using `is_numeric`.

Comment: For starters you shouldn't assume your desired `$_POST` (or `$_GET`) parameters will be there no matter what. You need to validate.

Comment: all your conditions are dependent on the post variable `marks`.  If you're not posting data to this php page, then those conditions will fail.

Comment: Best method `if(!empty($_POST['marks'])){ $Mymarks = $_POST['marks']; // rest of your code }`. `isset()` is mostly more effective with radios/checkboxes, IMHO. Let's see who catches on ;-)

Comment: @Srijan Mukherjee. It is happy to hear from you that your code is working fine. But it is the basic man to man help that you do who helps you in difficult times. It is a mandatory thing to accept and award the developer who has provided you with the code. Thanks and looking forward for your positive response. Happy coding :) Follow this link to mark answer as correct: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you directly access the PHP, it does not receive the POST value you are anticipating. You should include logic that first verifies `$_POST['marks']` is set, and handle appropriately if not.

For example:

```
if(isset($_POST['marks'])){
    //Handle
}
else{
    //Default
}
```

Comment: Cool, Mark it correct if you don't mind so others can easily reference it

Answer (score 1):

You have to check whether the values that are posted from the form exists and then make the condition according to it.

The function used to do so is called `isset()`.

> isset — Determine if a variable is set and is not NULL

**Description:**

Determine if a variable is set and is not NULL.

If a variable has been unset with unset(), it will no longer be set. isset() will return FALSE if testing a variable that has been set to NULL. Also note that a null character ("\0") is not equivalent to the PHP NULL constant.

If multiple parameters are supplied then isset() will return TRUE only if all of the parameters are set. Evaluation goes from left to right and stops as soon as an unset variable is encountered.

`Returns TRUE if var exists and has value other than NULL, FALSE otherwise.`

As per your example you need to perform the following actions.

```
 if(isset($_POST['marks']))
    $marks= $_POST['marks'];
else
    die("Mark not provided. Please Ensure you provide it.");
```

Comment: You can accept if my answer made your code working.. It is the basic help that you make to the developer who guides you when you are in trouble. Happy to hear it from you and awaiting for positive response from you :)

Comment: For Accepting the answer you may follow this link : http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work